# Merging Tables Correctly in SAS

Tags: sas

Hi I am trying to merge two tables the FormA scores table that I made that is now CalculatingScores with the domain number found in DomainsFormA. I need to merge them by QuestionNum. Here is my code.

```
  proc sql;
  create table combined as
  select *
  from CalculatingScores inner join DomainsFormA
  on CalculatingScores.Scores=DomainsFormA.QuestionNum;
  quit;
  proc print data=combined (obs=15);
  run;
```

This table is what I am trying to get my merged tables to look like but for 15 observations.

| Form | Student | QuestionNum | Scores | DomainNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| A | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 |  |
| A | 1 | 3 | 0 | 5 |

But My tables look more like this

| Form | Student | QuestionNum | Scores | DomainNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| A | 1 | 4 | 1 | 5 |  |
| A | 1 | 5 | 1 | 5 |

My entire Scores column for these 15 observations have a value of 1. Also my DomainNum column only has values of 5. My Student and Form columns are correct but I need to have varied scores and varied domain numbers. Any ideas for how to solve my problem? Maybe I need a order by statement?

Comment: You would better show us your input tables too.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be joining on the incorrect columns

You coded

```
on CalculatingScores.Scores=DomainsFormA.QuestionNum
```

which is joining a **score** to a **question number**

perhaps you should be coding

```
on CalculatingScores.QuestionNum=DomainsFormA.QuestionNum
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```